# Python optparse not working - syntax error

Tags: python, syntax, optparse

this script is based on another for an assignment. My code looks the same as theirs and BOTH error out with a syntax error. I am running with ActiveState Active Python 2.7 64-bit

```
def showEvents():
    ''' showEvents command

    List events from event logger with the following options:
    -t or -type (type of event to search for)
        warning (default option)
        error 
        information
        all
    -g or -goback (time in hours to search)
        integer
        default is 100 hours

    >>>showEvents -t warning -g 100
    type =  warning
    goBack = 100 hours
    '''
    import optparse

    parser = optparse.OptionParser()
    parser.add_option('-t', '--type', \
                        choices=('error', 'warning', 'information', 'all' ), \
                        help='write type to eventType', 
                        default = 'warning')
    parser.add_option('-g', '--goback', \
                        help='write goback to goback',
                        default = '100')
    (options, args) = parser.parse_args()
    return options

options = showEvents()

print 'type = ', options.type
print 'goBack =', options.goback, 'hours'

if options.type == 'all':
if options.goback == '24':
    import os
    os.startfile('logfile.htm')
```

This returns the defaults when it runs, but it wont accept input. What have I missed?

```
>>> type =  warning
goBack = 100 hours
>>> showEvents -t error
Traceback (  File "<interactive input>", line 1
    showEvents -t error
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

Thanks for looking.

Comment: What platform are you on? I can write a _general_ answer, but a specific answer will be different for Windows, Mac, linux, etc.

Comment: Also, your indentation was clearly wrong. I think I've fixed it, but please check and make sure it's the same as what you're running.

Comment: Indentation was just an artifact of posting the code here. Thanks for looking.

Comment: Yes, pasting here can sometimes be a problem. You have to look at the preview and make sure it's correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem isn't with your code, but with the way you're trying to test it.

`showEvents -t error` is not a valid line of Python, but it *is* a valid line of `sh` or `cmd`.

So, you don't type it into the Python interpreter, you type it into the bash/DOS prompt in a Terminal/DOS window.

Also, if you're not on Windows, the script will have to be saved as `showEvents` (rather than `showEvents.py`), and it will have to be installed somewhere on your `PATH`, and it will have to have the executable flag set, and it will need a `#!/usr/bin/env python` or similar first line. (Or you can skip all that and type `python showEvents.py -t error` at the bash prompt.)

On Windows, you can call it `showEvents.py`; as long as you're `cd`'d to the same directory it's saved in it's automatically on your `PATH`; and there is no executable flag or shebang line to worry about.

Comment: Excellent! Now that explains why theirs didn't work either. There was minimal direction when this assessment task was set. Also being distance there is next to no support.

Comment: Yeah, the assignment as written is pretty misleading. The docstring implies pretty strongly that you'll be typing this at the Python prompt (`>>>`), not the DOS (`C:\>`) or bash (`$`) prompt…

Comment: Thats my doc string.. from my understanding of the code requested, I will have to fix that now.